# how to change key name in typescript when defining type?

Tags: typescript

how to change key name in typescript?

I'd like to change it as follows.

```
type a = { num: number };
type b = Rename<a, 'number'>;
// b = { number: number; };

type aa = Array<{ num: number }>;
type bb = Rename<aa,'number'>;
// type bb = Array<{ number: number }>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you will likely need to use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) combined with [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).  Here's one possible way to do it:

```
type RenameObject<T, K extends keyof any> = T extends object
  ? { [P in K]: T[keyof T] }
  : T;

type Rename<T extends object, K extends keyof any> = T extends Array<any>
  ? { [I in keyof T]: RenameObject<T[I], K> }
  : RenameObject<T, K>;
```

Here, `RenameObject<T, K>` will leave a non-object type untouched, and rename an object type to a single-propertied object with key `K` and with property type equal to the (union of) the type(s) of `T`'s property(/ies).  And `Rename<T, K>` will apply `RenameObject` to the *elements* of `T` if `T` is an array; otherwise it will just apply `RenameObject` to it.

This behaves as desired for your two examples:

```
type a = { num: number };
type b = Rename<a, "number">;
// type b = { number: number; };

type aa = Array<{ num: number }>;
type bb = Rename<aa, "number">;
// type bb = Array<{ number: number }>;
```

But you didn't say what you want to see happen *in general*, so the above definitions have some behavior which you may or may not want to see if we stray outside of those use cases.

For example, I chose to make it so if `T` is a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) type, it produces a new tuple where each element is renamed separately:

```
type Tuples = Rename<[{a: string}, {b: number}, {c: boolean}], "hmm">
// type Tuples = [{ hmm: string; }, { hmm: number; }, { hmm: boolean; }]
```

And if `T` has more than one key, the resulting single-keyed object has a property which is the union of all of `T`'s property types:

```
type MoreThanOneKey = Rename<{ a: string; b: number; c: boolean }, "hmm">;
// type MoreThanOneKey = {  hmm: string | number | boolean; }
// they get merged into one key
```

And optional properties become required (this is a side effect but it would be more complicated to fix it and maybe you don't care):

```
type OptionalProperties = Rename<{ a?: string }, "hmm">;
// type OptionalProperties = {  hmm: string | undefined; }
```

And nested objects are only renamed one level deep:

```
type NestedObjects = Rename<{ a: { b: string } }, "hmm">;
// type NestedObjects = {  hmm: { b: string; }; }
```

And functions (which are technically objects in JS) become useless `never`-valued objects:

```
type Functions = Rename<() => 1, "hmm">;
// type Functions = { hmm: never; }
```

So, make of that what you will.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAShB2BDAthA8gIwFYQMbAB4AVAGigGkoIAPYBAEwGcoBrCEAewDMpF4QAfFAC8UIlVoNmHbHmAAoKFAD8UAN5QA2gAUoAS3gUAugC4xmtpx5EjUAL6KoZogG5580JFgIUEYhLp4JigZHHwyShpA4MtuXn4hUXEoqSgAQQAnDMQQAj5BR1UNTQBJfUNY61NvJFRMMMIiUqMIoQclMzha9Fl8Yla3D3BoRBF1KHgAV2QzKeQMCAz7N09oDDGu3zyyACI5hYydgTcAehOoddENfcXZ6YOXZfdV3lHRTOzc6+m7+cX7Y5DLwYS41LaIRC7G6HQFnKAvEFjD45AjfP4ZX4HAGDF5ESZgAA2EGYok2qAImjUiDMjGAGQMAHM7GQ1BhMYtmepcGYMBwOES+HYWlAdgALZDII7yOG4-FEklaDTimZQWn0+AMx6cpUS9kZLUsqDKnl8gXwLVGaXnCCIXCiqhE1DwYDleGi6DAOXQBkQYDMDI+VD0Z7DKAAWQ4AaIor4aHgEHI7A2gb8GmpqrpjMebIm90Wj25F1NNsMnLFEqOp3OLwjUZj8DjCaTVyUxoz6oZUAAPrn0d2i-yS1qrW6kz6XagMj76OVgBwQvHWOwQ140GBgHoOEgCdoMhxIBkN8Tk91UbxlDTMxr7LtlZWRy81xut4gd3uD0eFRojbr24z+5MQQQFwBgQPQw4yu6IAXHgHCoFAAYAI6THoAbBkC0AAHLEnQ9D1HICpkqmvBmBoOZqv+dg3iKd6wtWobYbSYH4fgX6tr+ZGXh2WoQdWUFQPQ87wBwLoBrgkwZIw0CCQA7oYBhzqqkwYGA76LJ+K7QAAYoB+CbvAhEpgQAAUACUIhCAAjLeFZ0fCoY6fAelbmxbbxgAbvm9gPvx468CKHmLDsUCqfu6kgO48hAA)